# Selecting the highest values from database, unique to customer name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Microsoft SQL database of many customers, the columns are `CustomerID,CustomerName,Locations,SQFT,EditDate, DateRecorded`

Every day, we record the square footage used by the customer. So the database should have a value for every day of the month. I want to select the day with the highest square footage use for every customer. The code below only returns a single customer, and not all customers. How can I return the highest SQFT for the month for each customer?

My code:

```
// $db_month_start = the first of the current month.
// $db_month_end = the end of the current month.
$query = "SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,SQFT,EditDate 
          FROM SquareFootage 
          WHERE DateRecorded >= '{$db_month_start}' 
          AND DateRecorded <= '{$db_month_end}' 
          AND SQFT = (Select Max(SQFT) From SquareFootage WHERE DateRecorded >= '{$db_month_start}' AND DateRecorded <= '{$db_month_end}') ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max SQFT per customer per month:

```
select  CustomerID
,       CustomerName
,       convert(varchar(7), DateRecorded, 120) as [Month]
,       max(SQFT) as MaxSQFTThisMonth
from    SquareFootage
group by
        CustomerID
,       CustomerName
,       convert(varchar(7), DateRecorded, 120)
```

This will work for any number of months, and customers that have their top SQFT for multiple days are only listed on one row.

Comment: you also need to group by year?  and this is for the current month only, not any given month

Comment: @Beth: `convert(varchar(7), getdate(), 120)` returns `2014-08`, so this groups on both the year and the month

Comment: This looks great. I did get the other code working, but I'd like to use yours too, for learning. How would I modify it to do a date range. Right now, I'm recording the current month data, but in the future, we'd like to search by a range of dates, either a specific month, or a group of months.

Comment: You can add a `where` clause between the `from` and the `group by`.  The `where` clause will be run before any rows are grouped.

Comment: @user1424232 . . . Note that this doesn't return the date of the month with the maximum value, which I thought you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow down the same path.  You just need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, SQFT, EditDate 
FROM SquareFootage sf
WHERE DateRecorded >= '{$db_month_start}' AND DateRecorded <= '{$db_month_end}' AND
      SQFT = (Select Max(sf2.SQFT)
              From SquareFootage sf2
              WHERE sf2.DateRecorded >= '{$db_month_start}' AND
                    sf2.DateRecorded <= '{$db_month_end}' AND
                    sf2.CustomerId = sf.CustomerId
             );
```

Comment: Looks to be working great. I had to add the closing `'` on this line `'{$db_month_end} AND` then it worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
   SELECT *, rank() over (partition by CustomerId order by SQFT desc) as [r]
   FROM SquareFootage 
   WHERE DateRecorded >= '{$db_month_start}' 
   AND DateRecorded <= '{$db_month_end}'
)
select CustomerID,CustomerName,SQFT,EditDate
from cte
where [r] = 1
```

This query reads as "For each customer, rank the records in reverse order by SQFT. Then, return the top record for each customer".